# Bigquery takes long time to write into shuffle for a small dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

Some queries that usually take 1-2 secs to execute are taking > 40 secs from time to time (same query, same dataset, no cache option), underlying (very very small) table has 311 records. When analyzing the job output for one that took 46 secs, I noticed that it spent most of the time by writing on shuffle.

Some stats on first stage (look at writing time)

```
"recordsRead": "7", 
"recordsWritten": "5", 
"shuffleOutputBytes": "130", 
...
"waitRatioAvg": 0.004167911256907963, 
"waitRatioMax": 0.007453206012353063, 
"writeMsAvg": "11795", 
"writeMsMax": "45886",
```

I know that query response time in BQ is non-deterministic, but this is a case where time response differ a lot from a expected response time range. Is this expected?

Example jobId: 946d8b64-7345-4c91-8ce9-66b04a2f6d0b

Comment: Maybe [post a bug on the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0)? Be sure to include the project ID or number with the job ID as well. It's hard to know why the time in shuffle is high without seeing the query.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Created bug [71737175](https://issuetracker.google.com/71737175)